# How can a PIR sensor light be made to work with a power bank?

Tags: led, pir

I am a software engineer by profession but love to tinker around with electronics.

I recently worked on an IOT project for a smart home using a Raspberry Pi and self aware modules consisting of an ESP8266 node MCU controlling 4 relays and running a small webserver to register themselves to the hub written in Flask and running on my Raspberry Pi.

I have worked with PIR sensors for  my kids' washroom to help them navigate at night.

I recently bought a 3 battery  powered LED lamp which uses a PIR sensor and an LDR to work only under low lumens. I do not have the schematic for the device nor any other knowledge about it since the manufacturer did not provide any technical details.

How can we connect a powerbank to a portable PIR LED light which is usually powered by 3 AAA batteries?

For example [this one.](https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B07QCXJ6S1/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_image_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

If the above link doesn't work then this is what I am talking about:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You haven't provided enough information. At a minimum we would need to see the manufacturer's specification for the light as well as the manufacturer's specification for the power bank. These things are not all exactly alike, and the differences matter.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson should i connect the power bank directly to the light or to put in a 1K resistor ?

Comment: You need to give a *lot* more information if you want us to give you any information on how. As the question stands, it's off topic for this site because it doesn't show enough effort on your part.

Comment: @Hearth I am a software engineer and do not know much about electronics and electricals. All i am asking is how would one connect a powerbank to this kind of a PIR sensor driven led light. 
I asked this question here because i though like the rest of the stack exchange and stack overflow communities, this one would have people who are helpful to noobs and not presumptions.

if you know the answer , pls share it. If not, pls let others respond.  :)

Comment: And i will update my original question with some more details about myself if that helps  :)

Answer (score 1):

You could probably connect the automatic light to the power bank.  It ought to work.  Three AAA cells in series provide just short of 5V.  Most power banks have a USB output with a 5V supply.  That all fits together.  The lamp has to be able to handle 5V because of the battery voltage and the power bank delivers 5V

The problem is that the lamp will be designed to use very little current when it isn't lit.

Every power bank I've ever used shuts off the 5V output when the load current drops below some value.  That's usually some few milliamperes or maybe tens of milliamperes.

Once the power bank shuts off, you have to either unplug and reconnect the load or you have to push a button to reactivate the 5V output.

You could try it out - nothing will break, it just might not work for more than a few minutes at a time.  If you are lucky, the lamp will draw enough current to keep the 5V output active.  If you aren't lucky, the power bank will shut off and you'll have to push a button to turn it on again.

---

If you are doing this because you want to learn about electronics, then by all means try it out.

If your kiddos really need an automatic light in the night, I'd look for something mains powered that'll **always** work.  You'd have to remember to charge/swap power banks as needed to be sure there's always power for the kiddos' late night hikes.  Mains is always there, unless you live somewhere with a bad distribution system.

Battery powered devices permanently installed **in** the house strike me as a waste and a pain.

---

Mmmpf.

Connection:

1. Buy a USB cable. Cut off the consumer end. That's the one that would normally go to the phone or camera or othe device.
2. Strip the wires, find the 5V output (often color coded red for 5V and black for ground.)
3. Connect 5V from the cable to the plus pole of the battery compartment.  That'll usually be a flat connector.  You may see a red wire connected to it.
4. Connect the ground from the cable to the minus pole of the battery compartment.  That should be a spring, and you may see a black wire connected to it.
5. Plug the modified cable into the power bank.  The light should work normally.
6. Let the light shut off, then wait a few minutes. Try triggering the lamp again (wave your hand at it or something.) If it still works, congratulations.

If if doesn't work, you can modify the 5V output of a cell phone charger wall wart the same way.

Comment: Thank you so much for your inputs JRE ! You are awesome! I will try and let you know.